# Add values from a dictionary to a ManytoMany field

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

```
class GuestOrder(models.Model):
    comment = models.CharField(max_length=400, blank=True, null=True)
    guest = models.ForeignKey(Guest, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    dish = models.ManyToManyField(Dish)
    ingredient = models.ManyToManyField(Ingredient)
    table = models.ForeignKey(Table, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
```

I have a queryset that returns 3 instances of GuestOrder.

```
guest_orders = GuestOrder.objects.filter(table=table)
<QuerySet [<GuestOrder: GuestOrder object (567)>, <GuestOrder: GuestOrder object (568)>, <GuestOrder: GuestOrder object (569)>]>
```

and I have a dictionary where values are dish instances.

```
{
    "guests":{
        "23": [1, 2],
        "24": [2],
        "25": [3]
    }
}
```

How to set each of this values to a guestorder instance?

This is what I tried (the name of the dictionary is guests)

```
for guestorder in guest_orders:
    for key, value in guests.items():
        guestorder.dish.set(value)
```

This only sets [3] as the dish

UPDATE

```
for guestorder in guest_orders:
    for key, value in guests.items():
        pass
    print(value)    
    guestorder.dish.set(value)
```

the result of the print is the following

```
[3]
[3]
[3]
```

and I don't understand why. I need help.

Comment: Can you show some code, what have you tried?

Comment: I'll update the question and add the code.

Comment: What is `23`, `24` & `25` here?

Comment: that's the guest id and 1-3 are dish id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I appended the dict values to a new list and iterated over the queryset and the list.

```
    for value in guests.values():
        dishes.append(value)
    for f, b in zip(guest_orders, dishes):
        f.dish.set(b)
```

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
for guestorder in guest_orders:
    for key, value in guests.items():
        guestorder.dish.add(value)

// or 


for guestorder in guest_orders:
   guest_list = []
   for key, value in guests.items():
       guest_list.append(value)
   guestorder.dish.set(guest_list)
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/

Comment: How this answer differs from the OP? I mean, what was the issue in OP?

Comment: I got this error TypeError: Field 'id' expected a number but got [1, 2]
I think I'll need to write a function that returns instances for [1, 2]

Comment: No I don't need to write a function for that cause it was already setting the dish.
I just need to figure out the right way.